# Rubocop rule to enforce double indent when assignment goes on next line

Tags: ruby, coding-style, rubocop

Our coding style says that if an assignment doesn't fit on one line, but the assigned value will fit on a line by itself, we should indent that line by four spaces instead of two. Example:

```
my_var = Some.reasonable_method_call(param1)
my_var2 = 
    Some.crazy_long_ridiculous_method_that_doesnt_fit_on_same_line(param1)
```

Is there a [Rubocop](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop) rule I can use to enforce this? We use a two-space indent inside a block, and the four-space indent for long assignments helps indicate visually that that line is not nested in a block but rather a continuation of the previous line.

Answer (score 2):

After looking through the rubocop source, it appears that the rule for alignment of parameters is in `/lib/rubocop/cop/style/align_parameters.rb line 34:`

```
 def base_column(node, args)
   if fixed_indentation?
     lineno = target_method_lineno(node)
       line = node.loc.expression.source_buffer.source_line(lineno)
         indentation_of_line = /\S.*/.match(line).begin(0)
 ------>  indentation_of_line + configured_indentation_width
   else
     args.first.loc.column
   end
 end
```

`configured_indentation_width` is defined in `lib/rubocop/cop/mixin/autocorrect_alignment.rb line 10:`

```
  def configured_indentation_width
 -> config.for_cop('IndentationWidth')['Width']
  end
```

That variable is stored in `/config/default.yml` which would require all your code to be set at 4 spaces instead of 2 (akin to Python PEP8).

Otherwise, you could just modify the source code of rubocop, to always require 4 spaces on a multi-line parameter assignment/method call.

Another (better) option would be to modify the source code, but to add a reference to a config variable, so that you're not using hardcoded values.